# finding the value local value of $f'(c)$

Tags: derivatives

I have differentiated: $$\frac{e^{2x}}{x^2+1}$$

to get:

$$\frac{2e^{2x}(x^2-x+1)}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

The follow question states:

What does it mean that $f$ has a local maximum at c? If $f$ has a local minimum at c and $f$ is differentiable at c, what is the value of $f'(c)$?

I have tried to find the values of x for which it is minimum however, substituting into  ${\sqrt {b^2 - 4ac}}$ there are no real roots?

Comment: The derivative is strictly positive on $\mathbb{R}\,$, so the function is strictly increasing, therefore has no minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we say that $f$ has a local maximum at $c$, then means that we basically 'have a downwards hill', in very plain terms. A local minimum means we have a 'upwards hill'.

Perhaps you can see what I mean by this here:

[image]

---

Do you notice anything special? These points $c$ are where, if you **were to take the slope**, it would equal $0$, since it is just a **horizontal line.** Thus, since the deriviative is a **mapping of the slopes**, to find the critical points, whether that it local max or min, we simply equate the **derivative** to $0$.

However in this case, the derivative never touches the $x-axis$, and so there are **no solutions** where the derivative $=0$. This means that there are $no$ critical points. Therefore there are no **local max/min.**

Comment: Would that mean that there is no value for $f'(c)$ as a result of no local min/max ?

Comment: The derivative is defined. But there is no $c$ value such that $f'(c)=0$

Comment: You can also graph the derivative on desmos,you will see that it never touches the x-axis